# Can I install an 8 speed sturmey archer hub on a dahon folding bike

Tags: hub

Can I install an 8 speed sturmey archer hub on a 6 speed dahon folding bike ?

Comment: What do you gain from going from 6 speed to 8 speed?   Is the 6 speed an IGH as well or is it a freewheel/derailleur bike?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether there are any challenges specific to a dahon bike, but here's a summary of the challenges you'll face converting any derailleur style bike to an internal gear hub:

- Hub width - You'll need to find an internal gear hub with the same width as the spacing between the dropouts.
- Chain tensioning - Derailleurs provide chain tensioning and with vertical dropouts you won't be able to adjust the tension with your IGH. You will probably need to install a chain tensioner.
- Replacing cable and shifter - You'll most likely need to replace the cable and the shifter.

Other than this there shouldn't be any reason you can't do this. Note that an internal gear hub will be heavier than your existing derailleur setup.

Given Dahon make other bikes with internal gear hubs it might be worth considering purchasing one with all the gear already sorted.

Comment: Many thanks, Mac, for your sensible comments and this is more or less what I was already thinking but I have not decided yet and I may sell the bike and start again with an upmarket folder.  Cheers Colin